# Resource Limits to be thrice of requests

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, helm3

In my values.yaml (which are more than 100) ; I just have resource requests mentioned. I added a logic in my helm deployment template which will make the limits as thrice of the requests. I am facing an issue with the units of memory and CPU. In some values.yaml; it is mentioned in Mi and in some as Gi for memory and 1 or 1000m for CPU. I tried to trim the unit to perform the multiplication and then I added "m" back. This would work in case the unit m but how can I do it for other units. I know this is not a best way to do this hence I am looking for a better approach.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvrDK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to parse your value, assuming your value contains only float (with of without dot) and suffix part as text, multiply float part and then append suffix later. Example, with 2x multiplication:

**values.yaml**

```yaml
limit: 1.6Gi
```

**pod.yaml**

```yaml
{{- $limit_value := .Values.limit  | toString | regexFind "[0-9.]+"  -}}
{{- $limit_suffix := .Values.limit | toString | regexFind "[^0-9.]+" -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: images.my-company.example/app:v4
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: {{ mulf $limit_value 2 }}{{ $limit_suffix }}
  - name: log-aggregator
    image: images.my-company.example/log-aggregator:v6
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
```

Result of `helm template`

```yaml
# Source: regex/templates/pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: images.my-company.example/app:v4
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: 3.2Gi
  - name: log-aggregator
    image: images.my-company.example/log-aggregator:v6
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
```

Notice usage of `mulf` instead of `mul`, it's required for float multiplication, `toString` function fixes type error if value specified without suffix.

Regexes are simple enough for proof of concept, you should make them stricter

Also, please don't use images of code to your questions, paste it directly,  see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: It worked when we have units defined but it throws an error when I use cpu: 2 (cpu: <number>)                                                                                                                         
   wrong type for value; expected string; got float64

Comment: Added toString to fix this error, also made example a bit cleaner